# Polymer 1.0 how to show the value of paper input in vaadin grid after pushing button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grid, polymer

I am trying to create some paper input in Polymer. When I click the "calculate" icon next to the item, it doesn't show the value or the result of paper input. It looks like it's getting the wrong in calling the value (?), and I'm not sure how to fix it? Thanks!

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selector.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/vaadin-date-picker/vaadin-date-picker.html">

<dom-module id="my-view2">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;

      }
      .form paper-icon-button{
        left: 45%;
        height: 120px;
        width: 120px;
      }
      .form paper-input{
        margin-left: 150px;
        margin-right: 150px;
      }

    </style>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="form">
      <paper-input type="number" name="satu" label="BLABLABLA1" value="{{todo.satu}}"></paper-input>
      <paper-input type="number" name="dua"label="BLABLABLA2" value="{{todo.dua}}"></paper-input>
      <paper-input type="number" name="tiga"label="BLABLABLA3" value="{{todo.tiga}}"></paper-input>


   <paper-icon-button src="calculator.ico" on-tap="_addTodo"></paper-icon-button>

      </div>
<vaadin-grid item="{todos}">
        <table>
          <colgroup>
            <col name="satu">
            <col name="dua">
            <col name="tiga">
          </colgroup>
        </table>
      </vaadin-grid>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-view2',
       properties: {
        todo: {
          type: Object,
          value: function() {
            return {};
          }
        },
        todos: {
          type: Array,
          value: function() {
            return [];
          }
        }
      },

      _addTodo: function() {
       this.push('todos', this.todo);
        this.todo = {};
      }

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your binding to `item` property of `vaadin grid` is invalid. You are missing one more brackets `{}`, plus property should be called `items` not `item` (according to documentation).

Comment: thank you for correcting the code. I have changed my code into '<vaadin-grid items="{{todos}}">', but still the colomn or the value of my paper input didn't show up on page. Can you help me? @Kuba Šimonovský

Comment: thank you for correcting the code. I have changed my code into '<vaadin-grid items="{{todos}}">', but still the colomn or the value of my paper input didn't show up on page. Can you help me? @KubaŠimonovský

Comment: following documentation, you should use `vaadin-grid-column` elements and not `<table>` inside `vaadin-grid`, but i have never used vaadin-grid before so i don't know if this is the problem. https://www.webcomponents.org/element/vaadin/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid

Additionaly, you should debug your application. Try to add console.log(this.todos), and so on.. try to debug it so you know where is the problem. it can be anywhere